# Google Earth Engine Error for random forest classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I am working on random forest classification to distinguish corn areas, and defining train and test data but I faced an error.

> classification: Layer error: ErrorMargin, argument 'value': Invalid
> type. Expected type: Float. Actual type: FeatureCollection

The code link is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2b9f525d17a57b6ab9f6e9a10b045f01

```
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//general collection
var l8collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterBounds(aoi.geometry())
                  .map(maskL8sr)

// Function to add an NDVI band, the dependent variable.
// More details: https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/si_product_guide.pdf
var addVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red']).rename('NDVI').float();
  var gndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'green']).rename('GNDVI').float();
  var grvi = image.normalizedDifference(['green', 'red']).rename('GRVI').float();
  var gbvi = image.normalizedDifference(['blue', 'green']).rename('GBVI').float();
    var ndmi = image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'swir1']).rename('NDMI').float();
var nbr2 = image.normalizedDifference(['swir1', 'swir2']).rename('NBR2').float();
  // Compute the EVI using an expression.
  var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('nir'),
      'RED': image.select('red'),
      'BLUE': image.select('blue')
  }).rename('EVI').float();
   // Compute VI using expressions
  var gcvi = image.expression(
    '(NIR/GREEN) - 1', {
      'NIR': image.select('nir'),
      'GREEN': image.select('green'),
  }).rename('GCVI').float();
  // Return the masked image, with additional bands for predictors.
  return image
      // Add the response variables last.
      .addBands([ndvi,gndvi, grvi,gbvi,ndmi, nbr2, evi, gcvi])
      // Retain this metadata property for use in the chart.
      .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
};

// Which bands to select:L8
var bandNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var bandNames = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2']);
// apply over the image collection
var l8collection = l8collection.select(bandNumbers, bandNames).map(addVI);
// Use the combined reducer - here just 25-75th
var reducersCol = ee.Reducer.percentile({percentiles:[25]})
                      .combine(ee.Reducer.percentile({percentiles:[50]}), null, true)
                      .combine(ee.Reducer.percentile({percentiles:[75]}), null, true);

var getNames = function(base, list) {
  return ee.List(list).map(function(i) {
    return ee.String(base).cat(i);
  });
};
//SEASON 1:
var startDate = '2020-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-09-28';
var s1 = l8collection
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
              .reduce({
        reducer: reducersCol
});
var s1New = s1.select(s1.bandNames(),
  getNames('season1_', s1.bandNames()));

print(s1New);
var vizParams = {bands: ['nir', 'red', 'green'], min: 0, max: 3000};
// to be added

var samples = corn.merge(noncorn);
//add export
// name of the bands
var bands = s1New.bandNames();
// extract band values from the input image
var samplesGeometry = samples.geometry(aoi).buffer(10); // Add a non-zero error margin of 10 meters
// Extract band values from the input image
var samplevals = s1New.sampleRegions({
  collection: samplesGeometry,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});

// define the random forest classier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
        numberOfTrees: 80,
        variablesPerSplit: 8,
        minLeafPopulation: 2,
        seed: 1});


// Train the classifier
var trained = classifier.train(samplevals, "landcover", bands);

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = s1New.select(bands).classify(trained);

// Display the inputs and the results.
//Map.centerObject(samples, 11);
Map.addLayer(s1New,{bands: ['season1_nir_p50', 'season1_red_p50', 'season1_green_p50'], max: 0.4}, 'image');
Map.addLayer(classified,
             {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['red', 'green', 'blue']},
             'classification');

// Step 1: Assign random numbers in preparation for a test/train split
var seed = 100;
samples = samples.randomColumn('random', seed);
// Join the landcover & random values with all pixels in each polygon in the training datasets.
var samplevals = s1New.sampleRegions({
    collection: samples,
    properties: ['landcover', 'random'],
    scale: 30
});

var seed = 100;
samples = samples.randomColumn('random', seed);
// Join the landcover & random values with all pixels in each polygon in the training datasets.
var samplevals = s1New.sampleRegions({
    collection: samples,
    properties: ['landcover', 'random'],
    scale: 30
});

//Step 2: Perform a  30/70 test/train split using the random numbers  generated in Step 1 to assess model performance.
var training = samplevals.filterMetadata('random', 'less_than', 0.7);
var testing = samplevals.filterMetadata('random', 'not_less_than', 0.7);
// Step 3: Train the classifier
// define the random forest classier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest({
        numberOfTrees: 500,
        variablesPerSplit: 8,
        minLeafPopulation: 2,
        seed: 1});
        
// Train the classifier.
var trained = classifier.train(training, "cropland", bands);
// Confusion matrix with independent samples
var validation = testing.classify(trained);
// Generate accuracy metrics
var errorMatrix = validation.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
// print results
```

Comment: Could you please share your AOI? It is difficult to understand the problem without it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help...                                  
This is the link for aoi: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-bbahmanabadi/assets/dasht_Qazvin

Comment: I do not understand why you create the variable samplesGeometry. If you just use the variable samples instead, it seems to work. However, you will get a “computation too large” error, but you can avoid it by using a bigger scale, for example 60 or else using fewer bands.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :)